# Local polynomial form of holomorphic functions

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, complex-geometry, cv.complex-variables

It is well-known that a germ of a holomorphic function of $n\geq 2$ variables, with at most an isolated singularity (*i.e.* the singularity of the analytic variety defined by the zero locus of the function), is locally conjugate (by right composition with a local biholomorphism) to a polynomial (in fact, a finite jet of the function).

This statement is not true anymore when $n\geq 3$ if the singularity is not isolated, although I can't find a reference containning examples of germs not locally conjugate to polynomials. Yet if I remember correctly, it is true when $n=2$.

Also I would be interested in knowing what happens in the meromorphic case, which I believe is still open.

I would be grateful for any pointer in the litterature towards such results!

PS: I hope this question is not a duplicate. I couldn't possibly browse through all the search results for requests  like «polynomial holomorphic function», and was unable to think about sharper keywords…

Comment: Singularities of analytic functions in dimension $n\geq 2$ cannot be isolated. Two functions $f,g$ are called conjugate if $\phi\circ f\circ\phi^{-1}=g$. Please edit your question.

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko: I'm not referring to dynamical conjugacy. I gave the meaning of conjugacy I'm after, that is $g=f\circ\phi$. This setting has been studied by _e.g._ Arnold, Mather, Tougeron, Yau. Besides I think you mistook the notion of singularity I'm referring to, that of tha analytic variety $\{f=0\}$, I edited the question to remove any ambiguity. In that setting the singularity of $f(x,y)=xy$ _is_ isolated at $(0,0)$. That being said, you might want to reconsider your downvote ;)

Comment: Teyssier: I recondisedered my downvote;-) though your usage of the term "conjugate" is very unusual.

Comment: Well, it's the conjugation for the right-action of the group of local change of coordinates, so from an algebraic point of view it's standard. Yet I agree that in general, analysis people (as I am) tend to think to the dynamical conjugation.

Comment: In the book by Greuel, Lossen and Shustin *Introduction to singularities and deformations* (page 118) this is called *right equivalence*. Actually,  I've never heard of the term "conjugation" used in this context, but I must say that I'm not really an expert in the field.

Comment: Let's admit my vocabulary was not standard, then :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The following example of non-algebraic germ is due to Whitney, see

H. Whitney: *Local properties of analytic varieties*, Differential and Combinatorial Topology 205–244, Princeton University Press (1965).

Take the germ of singularity in $\mathbb{C}^3$ given by $f(x,y,z)=0$, where $$f=xy(x+y)(x- zy)(x-e^zy).$$
The set $\{f=0\} \cap \{z= \lambda \}$ is given by five distinct lines through the origin.
If $f$ would be conjugate to a polynomial, the cross-ratios of any four of these lines would depend algebraically on $\lambda$. But this is impossible, because we have $\lambda$ and $e^{\lambda}$.

So this germ is *not* conjugate to a polynomial (or algebraic) germ.